# Add photo attribute to user collection in Kinvey

Tags: ios, kinvey

I wanted to add a profile photo to user collection when creating a user. I was thinking of doing `[user setValue:imageData forAttribute:@"photo"]` and then with help of `KCSLinkedAppdataStore` store it. But it fails with error **JSON serialization not supported for NSConcreteMutableData**.

```
[user setValue:imageData forAttribute:@"photo"];
KCSLinkedAppdataStore* store = [KCSLinkedAppdataStore storeWithCollection:[KCSCollection userCollection] options:nil];
[store saveObject:user withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *objectsOrNil, NSError *errorOrNil) {
    if (errorOrNil ==  nil) {
        //was successful!
    } else {
         //failed
    }
} withProgressBlock:nil];
```

Uploading the file separately and then set its `fileid` to an attribute in user collection works. What is the best way of extending `KCSUser`? I am currently using class extension.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to associate the profile photo with the user? 
http://support.kinvey.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200341553-Link-users-to-file-uploads?locale=en-us

Does this help answer your question?

Caroline

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Then one have to download this file every time it is needed. The main problem is extending KCSUser collection in the best way.